# MapView Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, maps

I am new to Android and i'm trying to create a MapView (Android 4.1.2) but when i launch the emulator, it shows me only the grey grid. 
I've got many errors:

```
11-15 14:04:42.916: E/MapActivity(691): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

and lot of these errors:

```
        11-15 13:57:04.186: W/System.err(691):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
```

When i created the key, my Fingerprint was in SHA1, not in MD5. I translated SHA1 to MD5 and i used it. The fact that the fingerprint was in SHA1, could be harmful?

What can i do?

Here's what i wrote.

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="it.alcos"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="it.alcos.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

layout where i created the mapView. I did insered the map-key, i'm hiding it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="********myKey*********"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Class.java. I added Zoom on the map, and nothing more.

```
public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    MapView mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: If it's a grey grid, I'm pretty sure your key is invalid. Are you sure  you signed it with your debug.keystore? If your key is invalid, your LogCat will have lots of exceptions about server responses not being correct

Comment: Are you sure the key corresponds to your keystore? Also, is the emulator able to access the internet through the browser?

Comment: Another possibility is that your device/emulator lacks Internet access or cannot reach the Maps servers due to firewall issues.

Comment: the emulator is able to access the internet through the browser.

Comment: Can you use Google Maps online through the browser?

Comment: Yet another possibility is that your Android device supports Google Maps but not the Maps API. That happens a lot with the poorly build kernels on a lot of cheap tablets.

Comment: Yes i can use GoogleMaps online through the browser...

Comment: The 'Couldn't get connection factory client' is a problem on google's side - don't worry about that. If by any chance you are using a proxy make sure your emulator is getting internet access. if you have a direct line, the only other thing is your key

Comment: When i created the key, my Fingerprint was in SHA1, not in MD5. I translated SHA1 to MD5 and i used it. 
The fact that the fingerprint was in SHA1, could be harmful?